# Why does C99 add keywords for complex type?

Tags: c, c99

I found that C99 added `_Complex` to support complex arithmetic. However, I wonder why C99 add new keywords for such a field-related feature (only useful for scientific calculation). Isn't it better to support complex type through standard library?

Comment: You cannot support operators like `+` through a library, C syntax doesn't allow that.

Comment: It's useful for many fields like [signal processing, control theory, electromagnetism, fluid dynamics, quantum mechanics, cartography, vibration analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Applications)

Comment: I don't see how this is "opinion-based" when there's an objectively verifiable answer in the Rationale document.

Comment: The Standard Committee decided to treat it like `_Bool` type (so if header is included, one can use it as `complex` type), as it's more natural to use in this way. Notice that C11 (current Standard) has lower requirements, notably `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` might be defined, thus `_Complex` type is effectively optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to the C99 Rationale document for information on why this decision was made:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

On page 42, lines 16-20 read:

> A new feature of C99: Complex types were added to C as part of the effort to make C suitable and attractive for general numerical programming. Complex arithmetic is used heavily in certain important application areas.
>
> The underlying implementation of the complex types is Cartesian, rather than polar, for overall efficiency and consistency with other programming languages. The implementation is explicitly stated so that characteristics and behaviors can be defined simply and unambiguously.

So it seems the underlying motivation was to make C more "attractive" or competitive for numerical programming, a field still dominated by Fortran if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: off the record - to help attract Fortran programmers to convert over to C